# node/npm/nvm not found error after macOS upgrade

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm, macos-big-sur, zshrc

node, npm, nvm all commands giving Command not found error on zsh terminal. This was working fine on macOS 11.2. After upgrading to 11.3.1 the command did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after upgrading macOS to 11.3.1 version. The upgrade reset my .zshrc file and removed the installed nvm entries from it. To resolve I added these lines again to the $HOME/.zshrc file and resolved the issue.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[[ -r $NVM_DIR/bash_completion ]] && \. $NVM_DIR/bash_completion
```